# Possible use case/real application for mobile distributed version of Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, smartphone

I'm developing this project where I'm trying to create a distributed version of [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) (the actual open source version is single node) and where the cluster is entirely composed by mobile devices (e.g. smartphones).

In your opinion, what is a possible application or use case where this could be useful? Can you give me some example please?

I know that this is not a "standard" Stack Overflow question, but I didn't know where to post it (if you know a better place where to post it, please let me know it). Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Maybe something like SETI@home?

Comment: You should post it at the [TensorFlow Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/discuss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.google.com.hk/search?q=teonsoflow+android

TensorFlow can be used for image identification and there is an example using the camera for Android.

There could be many distributed uses for this. Face recognition, 3D space construction from 2D images.

TensorFlow can be used for a chat bot. I am working towards using it for a personal assistant. The Ai on one phone could communicate with the Ai on other phones.

It could use vision and GPS to 'reserve' a lane for you on the road. Intelligent crowd planned roads and intersections would be safer.

I am also interested in using it for distributed mobile. Please contact me with my user name at gmail or Skype.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added you on skype. Btw I think that the biggest problem with these solutions is "why another user should use his mobile for someone else computation?". For example with a Face recognition application there should be only one user who tries to recognize some face and all the others collaborate to the computation...why should they do it?

Answer (score 0):

https://boinc.berkeley.edu

I think all my answers could run on individual phones with communication between them. If you want them to act like a cluster as @Yaroslav pointed out there is Seti@home and other projects running in the BOINC client.

TensorFlow could be combined with a game engine. You could have a proceduraly generated Ai learning augumented reality game generating the story as multiple players interact with it. I have seen research papers for each of these components.